# How draw a custom label border 3 sides right and 1 rounded

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I would like to draw the border of a label (UILabel) with three straight sides and a rounded as you can see an example picture: [example label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4PHg.jpg).

I use X-Code 7 and Swift 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shape layer and use it in the label. I tried to get close to the sample in Playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 170/2, width: 100, height: 30))


let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(1.5, 1.5, 97, 27), byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopRight, UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(15, 15))
rectanglePath.closePath()
let color = [#Color(colorLiteralRed: 0.8442155122756958, green: 0.9805876612663269, blue: 0.9611368179321289, alpha: 1)#]
color.setFill()
rectanglePath.fill()
color.setStroke()
rectanglePath.lineWidth = 3
rectanglePath.stroke()

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = rectanglePath.CGPath

label.textAlignment = .Center
label.backgroundColor = [#Color(colorLiteralRed: 0.990426778793335, green: 0.5112959146499634, blue: 0.4327127933502197, alpha: 1)#]
label.text = "Welcome...."
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
label.layer.mask = mask

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = color
view.addSubview(label)

XCPShowView("Label", view: view)
```

Comment: How I can add a shadow? Thank you.